# Android GridView Text overlapping

Tags: java, android, xml, gridview, overlapping

I try now for two days to create a working `GridView`, but it won't work, this is how it looks like:

[image]

You see, my problem is overlapping text.
I already found out, that the height of a `GridView` Row is set by the last item.
My XML looks so:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Startbildschirm">


    <GridView
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

My idea to fix this was to get the Height of the longest view in one Row and then set it as MinHeight to the last view. My problem was, that views are only saved as long they are visible, so on down and upscrolling the height was different again.
Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: If i understand your question, cells in the 2 columns are not the same height, but the row height is the height of the item in the second column ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your problem lies with the gridViewItem layout (the one you inflate in the adapter)
not with the gridview, i belive it has

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

somewhere,
just set the layout height there to have a fixed amount of dp

```
(android:layout_height ="10dp" for instance)
```

then you will not have a problem.

**edit based on comment:**
2 options - 
1)if the list isnt really long just use tableLayout and populate the rows in code, (the minus is that it doesn recicle views and therefor takes more memory than gridview) but it should get the effect you want (each row uses wrap content and adjusts to the length of text)

2)the adapter is using a list of some sort - run through it before using the grid and get the max height, now create a custom adapter that uses that (the max height) in your getView() to return approprite views (all of which big enough for max length)

Comment: That won't work, because the Height of the View depends on the length of the text, which is set in the Textboxes :/

Comment: @ich5003 a textbox to which you define a set size will just not show the text when its overflowing, the size of the view depends on the text becuase thats how you defined it i assume (share the item layout ill see for certain) at any case you can just create a method that cuts the text after a certain size something along the line of (if (s.length>max) then s=s.subString(0,maxChars)) that way your text is of the same size for each view

Comment: You're right, the height of the view depends on the text.
But I can't change that, because the text is different some times, and it has to show the whole text, so I can't just cut it.
My problem isn't to set views with a static height, I'm searching for a solution to set the MinHeight of one ROW as the Hieght of the longest view.
Maybe i described my problem a little bit wrong, but thx for your help though :)

Comment: Thx for your answer, I haven't tested it yet, but it sounds correct, so thx :)

Answer (score 4):

Another solutions is to keep parent of the cell to wrap_content, but to limit the TextView to for example 2 or 3 lines `android:lines="2"`
this all the views in the grid view will have the same size.

Answer (score 0):

I think, that a solution is described on: http://obduro.nl/blog/the-solution-of-android-gridview-overlap/.

It's reported as a bug in: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=75766

Comment: Thx for your answer :) But the new RecyclerView LayoutManager already solved the problem now :)